# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory - Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence.xml, hibernate-entitymanager

I am getting following error while deploying spring application with hibernate3 to glassfish server 3.1.2:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/home/konrad/NetBeansProjects/webapp/experimental/SpringBar2012_1/SpringWebApp4/target/training/WEB-INF/classes/persistence-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: webappPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.training.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>demoWebAppMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>SpringWebAppMVC</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-aegis</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>training</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <id>hibernate-support</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[hibernate-support]</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
        <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <properties>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <cxf.version>2.2.3</cxf.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

This is my persistence.xml file located in src/java/resources/META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="webappPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my persistence-context.xml file located in src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/webapp" />
    <property name="username" value="webapp" />
    <property name="password" value="java" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="webappPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean> 
</beans>
```

Could someone help me figuring out what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Your exception doesn't say why it was unable to build the entitymanagerfactory. You need to provide more details. What I do see wrong right now is that transaction type shouldn't be jta. Leave it default, because you are not using jta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I will try to answer your question.

The first thing is that you pasted the wrong part of error stack trace. Dig deeper and paste the real cause of this error.

The second thing is that your persistence unit configuration says that you will be using JTA.

```
<persistence-unit name="webappPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
```

In fact you have not specified JTA Transaction Manager.

There are two possible solutions:

- change 'transaction-type' to RESOURCE_LOCAL, so that JTA will not be used
- add JTA Transaction Manager configuration to your application

Try adding **hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class** and **jta-data-source** to your persistence unit:

```
<jta-data-source>...</jta-data-source>
<properties>
        ...
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
        ...
</properties>
```

Similar thread: [hibernate, mysql, glassfish v3, and JTA datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359640/hibernate-mysql-glassfish-v3-and-jta-datasource)

Comment: I changed to RESOURCE_LOCAL and problem dissapreared. I will replace it with JTA when I am really need it. Thank you for help.