# NetBeans, GlassFish and Hibernate JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

On work, im using Eclipse, Jboss and Hibernate JPA. For a smaller, private project I like to use Netbeans, GlassFish and Hibernate JPA.

Problem: I want hibernate to generate the tables automagically - but it won't do that for me.

What i did:

- First, i installed - obvious is obvious - Netbeans, Glassfish and a local MySQL-DB.
- I created a JDBC-Connection for Glassfish:

  url: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

  name: `myDatabaseJDBC`

  Driver: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

The connection seems fine, "testing" it resolved to a successful connection.

- Now i created the persistance.xml like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.0" 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>myDatabaseJDBC</jta-data-source>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  ```
- Then i added the required depoendencies to my Project (using maven) and the hibernate Plugin to Glassfish

What works: When ive created a table, in Netbeans i can Select `New -> Other -> Persistance -> Entity Class from Database`. The connection shows the tables, i select one, click okay, and i got the entity.

However i usually work *the other way round* and let hibernate generate my tables from the created entities... That whoever won't work. (It even looks like Hibernate is not even invoked, when building the project)

Did I miss any configuration step?

update: -------------

I wanted to test if hibernate is "active" in any way. So i created a simple entity, a controller and deployed the application with a single button.

```
public void doSth() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("primary");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    CEntity c = new CEntity();
    c.setName("Test");

    em.persist(c);
}
```

first, i received an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The chosen transaction strategy requires access to the JTA TransactionManager
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:376)
```

Overhere: [hibernate, mysql, glassfish v3, and JTA datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359640/hibernate-mysql-glassfish-v3-and-jta-datasource) i found the solution to add

```
// For GlassFish:
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup
```

to the persistance.xml. The exception is now gone, but i received another one: `Unknown Entity: CEntity`.

I figured out, that hibernate can NOT find my entities. (Yes, i used `javax.persistance.Entity` and not the one from the hibernate namespace). However "adding" the entity manually to the `persistance.xml` solves the issue and also the automatic table-creation is invoked.

However, now im looking for the correct configuration, so adding every Entity to persistance.xml is NOT required.

I set `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` but hibernate seems to ignore that...

Comment: where are you setting the connection parameters to mysql ?

Comment: @Stephan in the JDBC Connection. (including username, password, port)

Comment: Try this : <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/> , also you can check the mysql process list to see if any connections are present

Comment: Tried that also. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was to add:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
```

to persistence.xml's properties-collection. After all:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>myDatabaseJDBC</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```